# Turning off only some of layers specified using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, layers

I only know how to turn off the entire current layer. But I want off only some of the layers specified

```
#turn all layers in current map doc on:
print "Button2--turn on layers"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current")
list_layers = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames()
for layer in list_layers:
    layer.visible = True
```

Answer (score 3):

Just check for the name of the layers you want to turn off:

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, '')[0]

layersOff = ['layer2', 'layer3', 'layer5'] # Names of the layers you want turned off

list_layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df)
for layer in list_layers:
    layer.visible = True
    if layer.name in layersOff:
        layer.visible = False

arcpy.RefreshTOC()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

In this example, any layer names that match a name in `layersOff` are turned off, everything else is turned on.

Your `list_layers` was actually trying to get a list of Data Frames not layers, so I've added a `arcpy.ListDataFrames()` and corrected your `arcpy.ListLayers()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what to do with the following error ?

Comment: df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "layersOff")[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: take `layersOff` out of that line.  Should be `df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "")[0]`